# Update with Data from One to another Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

1. I have two databases: **db1 is server**, **db2 is local**.
2. **db2** I updated from the **db1** database.
3. And added 4000 new records to **db2**.
4. And I want to update **db1 (server)** from **db2 (local)**, but **some new records** have been added to **db1 (server)**.
5. Now when I want to do Restore Database, **some new records** from **db1 (server)** will disappear.
   How to make it so that when I update **db1 (server)** the added some records are not lost and
   new 4000 data added from **db2 (local)**? Can anyone tell me a way or a tool to compare the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to read/load the data from the local database to your server database.
This can be done via [Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) - if the servers are linked you can query data from the `db2` from the context of `db1`.

It will looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM [server].[db2].[schema].[table];
```

If this is not possible I am guessing you have another way to move the data there (via BCP command or maybe just script the table and the data using [SSMS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b19d5a/generate-database-script-with-table-data-from-sql-server-2008/) from `db2` and create it in `db1` (4000 rows is not much and you should be OK to just copy the generated SQL).

Now, having the data in one place, you must have a way to identify which rows to insert.

This can be done easily like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM db2Table
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM db1Table
```

So, if there is row in the `db2Table` that is not found in the `db1Table` it will be returned. Then, just insert these rows.

Please, note that `EXCEPT` with `*` is comparing all columns. So, if you have a column like `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` you will need to exclude it from the `SELECT` list.

Also, if you have a way to map the data between the two tables by `ID` or `GUID` (a lot of folks are using UNIQUEIDENTIFIER to synch data), you make perform more complex operations. For example:

1. If the `GUID` record is missing in the `db1` table - insert it
2. if the `GUID` record is found in the `db1` table - update it